# Generate all combination of element values if reference match

Tags: xml, xslt, text, xslt-2.0

I'm struggling with this XML that has nonuniform structures. The first `<Report_Data>` should be the reference of the 2nd and 3rd `<Report_Data>`. So what will happen is that when `GL_Code` and `Code` are identical with `PT-BU_Code`, their element values must be copied. If there are no additional details on the 2nd and 3rd `<Report_Data>` for the 1st `<Report_Data>`, the entries must retain.

```
<RaaSData>
<Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.bsvc">
    <Report_Entry>
        <PT-BU>A0003 SPL</PT-BU>
        <PT-BU_Code>A0003</PT-BU_Code>
    </Report_Entry>
    <Report_Entry>
        <PT-BU>CAN01 RIS</PT-BU>
        <PT-BU_Code>CAN01</PT-BU_Code>
    </Report_Entry>
    <Report_Entry>
        <PT-BU>NL001 REG</PT-BU>
        <PT-BU_Code>NL001</PT-BU_Code>
    </Report_Entry>
    <Report_Entry>
        <PT-BU>ZA009 CJH</PT-BU>
        <PT-BU_Code>ZA009</PT-BU_Code>
    </Report_Entry>
</Report_Data>
<Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.bsvc">
    <Report_Entry>
        <GL_Code>A0003</GL_Code>
        <Book_Code>G</Book_Code>
    </Report_Entry>
    <Report_Entry>
        <GL_Code>A0003</GL_Code>
        <Book_Code>L</Book_Code>
    </Report_Entry>
    <Report_Entry>
        <GL_Code>CAN01</GL_Code>
        <Book_Code>L</Book_Code>
    </Report_Entry>
</Report_Data>
<Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.bsvc">
    <Report_Entry>
        <Cost_Center>67902 CC</Cost_Center>
        <COMPANY>
            <Code>A0003</Code>
        </COMPANY>
    </Report_Entry>
    <Report_Entry>
        <Cost_Center>99999 CC</Cost_Center>
        <COMPANY>
            <Code>A0003</Code>
        </COMPANY>
        <COMPANY>
            <Code>NL001</Code>
        </COMPANY>
    </Report_Entry>
</Report_Data>
</RaaSData>
```

I ain't really sure how to start my XSLT but here's an example of the output I would like to achieve (in ascending order based on `PT-BU_Code`). Notice that new entries are generated and are all unique depending on the element values given in the 2nd and 3rd `<Report_Data>`.

```
Company;Code;Cost Center;Book Code
A0003 SPL;A0003;67902 CC;G
A0003 SPL;A0003;67902 CC;L
A0003 SPL;A0003;99999 CC;G
A0003 SPL;A0003;99999 CC;L
CAN01 RIS;CAN01;;L
NL001 REG;NL001;99999 CC;
ZA009 CJH;ZA009;;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use keys to look up the company and book information

```
<xsl:key name="book" match="Report_Entry" use="GL_Code" />
<xsl:key name="company" match="Report_Entry" use="COMPANY/Code" />
```

But then it becomes a bit messy as you need to check for the case where you have a book, but no company, or a company but no book, or both, or neither.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:key name="book" match="Report_Entry" use="GL_Code" />
  <xsl:key name="company" match="Report_Entry" use="COMPANY/Code" />

  <xsl:template match="RaaSData">
    <xsl:text>Company;Code;Cost Center;Book Code&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="Report_Data[1]/Report_Entry">
      <xsl:variable name="bu" select="PT-BU_Code" />
      <xsl:variable name="prefix" select="concat(PT-BU, ';', $bu, ';')" />
      <xsl:for-each select="key('company', $bu)">
        <xsl:variable name="company" select="Cost_Center" />
        <xsl:for-each select="key('book', $bu)">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat($prefix, $company, ';', Book_Code, '&#10;')" />
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="not(key('book', $bu))">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat($prefix, $company, ';', '&#10;')" />
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:if test="not(key('company', $bu))">
        <xsl:for-each select="key('book', $bu)">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat($prefix, ';', Book_Code, '&#10;')" />
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="not(key('book', $bu))">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat($prefix, ';', '&#10;')" />
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```